# Key Vault - Firewalls and virtual networks: Existing virtual network is not authorized

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I configured the key vault to sign JWTs from my application and I limited the access to a specific virtual network and related subnet. At the beginning was working fine but suddenly it stopped working giving me the following error:

```
{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Client address (52.166.11.176) is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service","innererror":{"code":"ForbiddenByFirewall"}}}
```

I had to allow all the networks to fix the problem.

Do you have any idea about this behaviour?

Thank you

Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal that the error happened because you had restricted restrict access to a specified virtual network, but the Client address was not coming from that authorized network. Please note that

> The virtual network service endpoints for Azure Key Vault allow you to
>   restrict access to a specified virtual network. The endpoints also
>   allow you to restrict access to a list of IPv4 (internet protocol
>   version 4) address ranges. **Any user connecting to your key vault from
>   outside those sources is denied access**.

I suggest that you finish the key vault configuration before you limit the network access to a specific virtual network.

Ref: [Virtual network service endpoints for Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-overview-vnet-service-endpoints)

Comment: Hi Nancy, thank you for the answer. I did exactly what you said and the error is pretty clear to me. I just don't understand why it stopped to work. Anyway, before answering you I tried to remove the virtual network and added it again, enabling the service endpoint for Azure key vault and it started to work again. Not sure, just a bit worried If I think I have to go for production and suddenly could stop to work. Let's see. Thanks again

Comment: As my reply explained it's normal to see this error. `why it stopped to work`? I think that's because you enabled the subnet in Azure keyvault firewall after you configured the key vault. At the beginning was working fine because you had not enabled the subnet in Azure key vault firewall for the first time, is this true on your side? You may know what is the ability of the service endpoint.